# Determine whether the function is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> $T:V \to R$, where $V$ is an inner product space, and $T(u)=\Vert u \Vert$

To establish if it is linear we have to test these two axioms:
a) $T(u + v) = T(u) + T(v)$
b) $T(ku) = kT(u)$

possibly check that $T(0) = 0$ also
$T(0) = \Vert 0 \Vert = 0$
a) $T(u + v) = \Vert u + v \Vert \le \Vert u \Vert + \Vert v \Vert \neq T(u) + T(v)$ all the time.
b) $T(ku) = \Vert ku \Vert = |k|\Vert u \Vert \neq kT(u)$

So this is not a linear transformation.

Can anyone check over this for me please? For point a) i'm not sure how to say that this is not equal because obviously sometimes it is and sometimes it isn't.
I worded it to say that the expression is not equal to $T(u) + T(v)$ all the time.
Thanks

Comment: Note that $T(0)=0$ ensues from $T(ku)=kT(u)$ with $k=0$, so you don't have to verify it explicitely. Thought it could be the quickest counter-example if not verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the "axioms" in the definition are universal, you only need one of them to be wrong once for the whole thing to be off.

As long as your $T$ isn't identically zero*, some $T(u)$ must be positive. Then $T(-u) \neq -T(u)$ for this $u$ and you're done.

You also need to be careful in your b).  You assert that $T(ku) \neq kT(u)$, but this could actually be true a lot of the time (let $k=1$).

(*) I suppose this is automatic by positive definite-ness, as long as $V$ isn't trivial.

Comment: thanks for your help. I was going to only use one of them, but then I thought someone would say I was being lazy. Good to know you can be efficient here. For b) I didn't see that. Thanks for pointing that out.  I would also have to say that this statement is only true when $k$ is not negative. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

No, Linearity doesn't hold.
 $||u+v||\leq||u||+||v||,\forall u,v\in V$. Equality holds only when $u=\kappa v$, where, $\kappa $ is any scalar.